# How to change the number of post result that shows in page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

Why it only shows 10 post results even if there are more?

```html
<div class="job-cont">
    <?php 
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs' ) );

   if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

       while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="title_image_container">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink (); ?>">
                   <h1 class="the_job_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                   <img class="the_job_image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail ();?>
               </a> 
        </div>   
     <?php  endwhile;

   endif;
      ?>
  
  </div>
```

It's there a way to change the number of posts that I want to be showed in the page?

I all ready tried this one, but without result yet:

```
function number_of_posts_per_page( $number ) {
        if ( is_home() ) {
        $number->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );         
    }

    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'number_of_posts_per_page');
```

Comment: What? Write some more details, no idea what you're speaking about

Comment: Yes. Sorry, hope now it's better to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has default setting as 10 posts per page.

For blog posts, you can adjust settings in Settings -> Reading

For custom post type you can adjust maximum posts per page directly in loop query as in the code below where -1 means unlimited.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' =>  'jobs', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
```